# Purchasing iOS Subscription makes app stuck without a response from StoreKit

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, in-app-subscription

Our live application has a user reach out to us and report that his app gets stuck (with the loading indicator) when he tries to purchase a subscription. He shared a video of it, he is not shown any alert or popups or sheets by StoreKit confirming the subscription or informing the result etc. Any one ever face this kind of issue before or know the cause of it. As far as we know, this issue is only occurring for one user, subscription works correct in sandbox environment (both Xcode and TestFlight). Do let me know if any other information is needed. Please and thank you.

Here is the code for purchasing:

```
func purchase(_ product: SKProduct, completion: @escaping IAPBlock) {
        guard canMakePayments else {
            completion(.failure("Purchases are disabled on your device!"))
            return
        }
        
        guard SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions.last?.transactionState != .purchasing else {
            completion(.failure("Pending purchase is already in processing. Please try again later!"))
            return
        }
        
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        let queue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
        queue.add(payment)
        queue.add(self)
}
```

SKPaymentTransactionObserver:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        transactions.forEach{
            switch $0.transactionState {
            case .purchasing, .deferred:
                break
            case .purchased:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)
            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)
            case .failed:
                if (($0.error as? SKError)?.errorUserInfo["NSUnderlyingError"] as? Error)?.localizedDescription == "You’re currently subscribed to this." {
                         refreshReceipt()
                         // "Subscription restored!"
                        }
                        else {
                            // error
                        }
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction($0)
            @unknown default:
                        fatalError()
                    }
                }
            }

private func refreshReceipt() {
        let request = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        self.delegate?.receiptRefreshing()
    }
```

I have removed the code that does internal app stuff on success and failures etc to keep the code above relevant to the purchase flow.

Comment: Without any code or log details it's nearly impossible to suggest anything. Add some logging to the app and show us the code and the logs.

Comment: I was not sure if the code would help since there is only 1 user(to our knowledge) that is facing this issue and rest are able to use subscriptions properly. But In any case, I have now added code as well.